# tomcat7 clickstack not finding Config params

Tags: cloudbees

I am testing the tomcat7 clickstack for our application which has some config parameters set using the built in Config features of Cloudbees.  The tomcat7 clickstack does not find them, but the standard tomcat6 container does.  I have double checked them and reset them through the cloudbees sdk and they are there and correct, but are coming back as null for tomcat7.

Answer (score 0):

The switch to clickstacks requires us to refactor how the servlet container gets configured so that the injection points such as `cloudbees-web.xml` and jvm system properties behave consistently across all the servlet container clickstacks.

[Some](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-clickstack/commits/master) of that refactoring has been committed but some of the work is still in my backlog... Assuming none of the other bees steal that task from my backlog before I get to it ;-)

IF I recall correctly, the parameters should be available as environment variables (sub optimal I know, but all containers should be giving this as a consistent UX for all clickstacks, eg both non-java based and java-based) and may be already available as system properties (again sub optimal, but the java container refactoring should be giving this as a consistent UX for all java based clickstacks). The consistent java servlet UX has not been committed yet but should be available soon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stephen.  I'll continue with Tomcat 6 for now and follow the Tomcat 7 progress